# H2 - Error accessing linked table with SQL statement "SELECT * FROM null T"

Tags: java, mysql, h2

I try to created linked table in my Java application.

```
Statement stmtH2 = DBconnect.connH2.createStatement()
String linkedTable = ("CREATE LINKED TABLE tableName('', 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBname', 'root', '', 'tableName');";
stmtH2.execute(linkedTable)

String query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Sex = 'F' ORDER BY Cod";
stmtH2.executeUpdate(query);
```

In Java I've got this error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "COD" not found; SQL statement:
```

When I try to see the table in localhost:8082 running `SELECT * FROM tableName` an error comes up:

```
Error accessing linked table with SQL statement "SELECT * FROM null T", cause: "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Class ""com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"" not found [90086-175]"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM tableName [90111-175] 90111/90111 (Help)
```

Why column "COD" is not found?

Comment: `Error accessing linked table with SQL statement "SELECT * FROM null T"` ->  seeing `NULL` in java applications is always suspicious ... i would suggest sharing some more Java and MySQL/h2 code..

Comment: I edited question adding details

Answer (score 1):

Your application is missing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Add it to the classpath of your application.

Comment: I've got it in the classpath, because I have other statements that work

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that there is no `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in the classpath of H2. If you use the H2 Server, you need to add this driver to its classpath. Also H2 1.3.175 is very old, you shouldn't use it. Use some recent version such as 1.4.199. Beware: you need to export your old database to the SQL script in 1.3.175 and execute it in the new empty database in 1.4.199, automatic migration of legacy PageStore databases does not always work properly.

Comment: As I said in a previous comment I have Driver in the classpath because there are other statements in my application that create linked tables and then select from these linked tables that works. The error relative to missing Driver occur in H2 console. In my application comes up the SQLException. I have in my application similar select statement but with different table and they works. Only with the table  ```tableName ``` it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you create other tables from the H2 Console too? How exactly your `CREATE LINKED TABLE` command looks like? What is the complete stack trace (you need to click on an error message to open it)?

Comment: I didn't create linked tables from console. Forget the console. I work only in my Java application. I created all the linked tables in this application.
The linked table ```tableName``` is created.
I verified its columns with ```String query = "SELECT * FROM tableName";```, ```ResultSet filter = stmt.executeQuery(query);```
```ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = filter.getMetaData();```
```System.out.println(rsMetaData.getColumnName(2));```
The last command print "Cod", but when I try to run ```SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Sex = 'F' ORDER BY Cod``` it says that column COD is not found.

Comment: Even if I run ```SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Sex = 'F'``` it says that Column SEX is not found, but the column is present on linked table ```tableName```

Comment: You need to use the quoted names (in double quotes), like `"Cod"` and `"Sex"` to access columns with lower case characters in their names. Recent versions of H2 convert column names of linked tables from MySQL to upper case to avoid such issues, but you use an old version.

Comment: @Evgenij Ryazanov if you converted the last comment in answer I can accept this as a solution.